# Bootstrap 3 margin issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a slight margin to the right which gets larger as the site is shrunk.  The previous fix was to remove this from my stylesheet:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

That doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: I guess I don't see the margin getting larger.  What browser are we talking?

Comment: On some pcitures you are setting an inline style with margin - left 11% that's breaking the layout

Comment: No, they are not breaking the layout. You need to learn to use bootstrap's grid. Each `.row` had a negative margin. You need to use a `.container` and then a `.row` and then children columns `.col-lg-12` and so on. column, inside a row, inside a container. That will work

Comment: The margin-left: 11% is not the cause.  I removed them and the right margin is still there.

Comment: Do I need multiple container divs, or is one with all the .rows included in it enough?

Comment: Depends on your layout. If you have variable row width, you need a container for each set of rows that share same width value, if not, one container is enough.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me a lot too. 99% of the time it is caused by NOT wrapping your `.rows` in a `.container` class. I haven't had a chance to pick through your code, but that would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

And btw, the problem is with your `<div class="row no-gutter" id="just">`. Wrap it inside a `div.container` and you're all fine.

Comment: That still didn't solve it.. as when I shrink the layout the right margin re appears.

Comment: Seriously? I gave you the solution, and you can't even check again the breakpoint for tablet/mobile? Way to go, you don't want a solution, you want someone to fix your multiple issues. Please, learn to use bootstrap :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am new to bootstrap so am certainly not 100% on all the ins and outs yet.  Trying to learn so that's why I'm asking questions here.  I did wrap that div in a container div, and the problem still exists.  I will get it figured out.